# Link several spinners to each other and make each item just one time selectable

Tags: android, android-spinner

I've got my "OrderActivity" where I receive order details with a List of ordered articles. For every article I have a Spinner, where you can select the storage location. If an article already exists in the storage, I show the current storage location and deactivate the spinner, because each article is just allowed to be in one storage location. Now for those articles that are not already stored in our storage, the user should select the storage loaction he wants to put the article in. If in the list of possible "empty" storages one is selected for a new article, this spinneritem (storage location) should not be selectable by any other spinner (so I sort of want to delete it from the selectable spinner items).
Has anyone got an idea how to do so?